# Combining Ranges in Excel Functions with out helper cells

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, office365, let

I am having difficulty figuring out how to get the correct data type evaluated as a single array passed to the first argument of the Small() in this function. My overall goal is (completely without the use of helper cells) to combine two sets of ranges passed to Small() as arrays into a 2-dimensional array output. The formulas work correctly when placed separately in ranges, but when combined in a Let() I get type inconsistency caused #VALUE! errors as the output.

Here is the LET() function ...

```
=LET(
A1v, SEQUENCE(1,10,1,0),
A2v, SEQUENCE(1,10,2,0),
SMALL((A1v,A2v),SEQUENCE(2,COLUMNS(A1v)))
)
```

When the Let() formula is broken into pieces and placed into separate ranges as described below it produces the desired output in A3:J4 (A3#) as shown in this

[image: image of formula results when entered in separate cells]

Range A1 formula:

```
 =SEQUENCE(1,10,1,0)
```

Range A2 formula:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,10,2,0)
```

Range A3 formula:

```
=SMALL((A1#,A2#),SEQUENCE(2,COLUMNS(A1#)))
```

I am aware that there are other function constructs that can be used to combine ranges. I am not looking for alternatives to using Small(). I am looking for answers that will help further my understanding of constructing arrays from and to be used as inputs to the new array functions in Excel. Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `Let` function fails is the `(A1v,A2v)` parameter to `Small`.  That construct is the Union Operator for *Ranges*.  `A1v` and `A2v` are arrays, not ranges.

This can be seen in the Formula Evaluator dialog

[image]

[image]

In contrast `(A1#,A2#)` works because `A1#` and `A2#` *are* ranges.

FWIW, `Small` itself can accept either ranges or arrays

---

To solve this you'll need a general purpose solution to getting the Union of two data sets, whether they be Ranges or Arrays.  This can be achieved using a [`Lambda` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67).

1. Add a Workbook scoped Name to the Name Manager, lets call it `Union`
2. In the Refers To section insert

   ```
   =LAMBDA(tabl1, tabl2,
       LET(rowindex, SEQUENCE(ROWS(tabl1)+ROWS(tabl2)),
           colindex, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(tabl1)),
           IF(rowindex<=ROWS(tabl1), 
              INDEX(tabl1,rowindex,colindex),  
              INDEX(tabl2,rowindex-ROWS(tabl1),colindex)
           )
       )
   )
   ```
3. `Union` is now available to use as a stand alone function, or imbedded in another function
4. Your Formula now becomes

   ```
   =LET(
       A1v, SEQUENCE(1,10,1,0),
       A2v, SEQUENCE(1,10,2,0),
       SMALL(Union(A1v,A2v),SEQUENCE(2,COLUMNS(A1v)))
   )
   ```

[image]

Or without Lambda

```
=LET(
    A1v, SEQUENCE(1,10,1,0),
    A2v, SEQUENCE(1,10,2,0),
    rowindex, SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1v)+ROWS(A2v)),
    colindex, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A1v)),
     Av, IF(rowindex<=ROWS(A1v), 
           INDEX(A1v,rowindex,colindex),  
           INDEX(A2v,rowindex-ROWS(A1v),colindex), 

   SMALL(Av,SEQUENCE(2,COLUMNS(A1v)))     )
    )
```

Untested, so you might have to tweak it a bit

Comment: I knew that was the problem, I just couldn't find a mechanism to turn the arrays into ranges to feed into Small. I was hoping there was some function or construct syntax that I just overlooked. I would love to have access to the Lambda function, but my work is on the Monthly Enterprise Channel release of 365 so that is not an option right now. Unfortunately, I guess I'll have to write one in VBA as a UDF.

Comment: To be clear, it's not passing Ranges to Small that's the issue, it's the`(A, B)` construct that only works with ranges.  You can probably use the inner workings of the Lambda to write a (complex) formula.  Or write a UDF called Lambda, that mimics its functionality